# Can't find native library in lldb

Tags: lldb

・I am analyzing an Android app that was in the CTF.
(https://github.com/TRkizaki/cryptoverse2023/tree/main/reverse_java_not_interesting)

・In this app, the input string is checked by the checkvaild function in the native library (libhello-jni.so).
　Then, if the input string is correct, a flag is displayed.
・Since debuggable is set to True in this app, I would like to use 「lldb」 to do the dynamic analysis.
However, libhello-jni.so is not displayed when I use the "image list" option after attaching with lldb.

Why is this?

・The host environment is Windows and the application is installed on a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the library is loaded on-demand, when the JNI function is invoked. Maybe try putting breakpoints on `dlopen`/`dlsym` and see if it's present then.